# Formatting list by applying `Re` and `Im`

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of the form
$$\{\{ a_1, b_1\}, \{a_2, b_2\}, \cdots, \{a_n, b_n\}\},$$
where $a_1\in\mathbb R$ and $a_2\in\mathbb C$. I want to change the list to
$$\{\{ a_1, \mathrm{Re}(b_1), \mathrm{Im}(b_1)\}, \{a_2, \mathrm{Re}(b_2), \mathrm{Im}(b_2)\}, \cdots, \{a_n, \mathrm{Re}(b_n), \mathrm{Im}(b_n)\}\}.$$
How can I do this?

The example for the list is:

```
{{-1/1000000000000, 2.55283390977069556204008716705554506138`23.921888358240608 + 
   3.48707098384782539223398113770432855356`24.057326586294764*I}, 
 {-1/(1000000000000*10^(1/5)), 2.55290682732132583751657515484269601895`23.92189330339674 + 
   3.48710959833737966226927540946055307283`24.05732393589644*I}, 
 {-1/(1000000000000*10^(2/5)), 2.55296936917139129855547369554609524695`23.92189754471748 + 
   3.48714271782658979662184894629557723327`24.057321662650814*I}, 
 {-1/(1000000000000*10^(3/5)), 2.55302301162313513499489662579267524484`23.92190118239305 + 
   3.48717112427658142494970308896243105679`24.057319712890102*I}, 
 {-1/(1000000000000*10^(4/5)), 2.55306902094847477674640724228380000069`23.921904302347855 + 
   3.48719548837219013029111068862614788291`24.057318040582995*I}, 
 {-1/10000000000000, 2.55310848326302773849319357445614699881`23.921906978272762 + 
   3.48721638535703987612702056305755260672`24.05731660624813*I}}
```

Comment: What about `{#[[1]], Re[#[[2]]], Im[#[[2]]]} & /@ w`, where `w` is your list?

Comment: @yarchik Thanks, it works! I think this should be an answer.

Comment: No, it is a small thing. I recommend to close the post.

Comment: Also look at the `ReIm` function.

Comment: `MapAt[Apply[Sequence]@*ReIm, list, {All, 2}]`

Comment: Thanks for all of you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

```
list1 = {{-1/1000000000000, 
   2.55283390977069556204008716705554506138`23.921888358240608 + 
    3.48707098384782539223398113770432855356`24.057326586294764*
     I}, {-1/(1000000000000*10^(1/5)), 
   2.55290682732132583751657515484269601895`23.92189330339674 + 
    3.48710959833737966226927540946055307283`24.05732393589644*
     I}, {-1/(1000000000000*10^(2/5)), 
   2.55296936917139129855547369554609524695`23.92189754471748 + 
    3.48714271782658979662184894629557723327`24.057321662650814*
     I}, {-1/(1000000000000*10^(3/5)), 
   2.55302301162313513499489662579267524484`23.92190118239305 + 
    3.48717112427658142494970308896243105679`24.057319712890102*
     I}, {-1/(1000000000000*10^(4/5)), 
   2.55306902094847477674640724228380000069`23.921904302347855 + 
    3.48719548837219013029111068862614788291`24.057318040582995*
     I}, {-1/10000000000000, 
   2.55310848326302773849319357445614699881`23.921906978272762 + 
    3.48721638535703987612702056305755260672`24.05731660624813*I}}
```

then

```
list1 // N // TableForm
```

[image]

is a nice and simple table of the value truncated to a reasonable length. `N` offers options to select the preferred length of digits after the comma.

Nicer is

```
TableForm[list1 // N, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}, {"a1", "b1"}}]
```

[image: formatted TableForm]

```
TableForm[#[[1]], ReIm[#[[2]]]} & /@ list1, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}, {"a1", "Re(b1)", 
    "Im(b1)"}}]
```

[image]